# ASP.Net/SQL: After cancelling query the memory isn't decreasing (DataBoundControl.PerformSelect)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, ado.net, memory-leaks

In an asp.net 2.0 production environment we have an aspx that queries all kind of query's to a SQL2005 database. Some queries will take a while so we added a cancel button.

In code we are opening the connection and after that we call command.ExecuteReader(). We bind it to a gridview.

In the cancel button click we call command.Cancel(), dispose the command, the connection and the datareader. And also close the connection.

After the code is executed I see in SQL profiler the query is cancelled. But the w3wp.exe still is using a lot of memory.

To test it I wrote a query that returns a lot of data. In 2 seconds I cancell it and what I see is that the memory is increased from 250Mb up to almost 2Gb. After a while the memory isn't decreased.

I've used JetBrains dotTrace Memory 3.5 to see what's going on with the memory. What I see is that 66,6% of the memory is in use by DataBoundControl.PerformSelect. Microsoft says "The PerformDataBinding method is called after data is retrieved to bind data to elements of the data-bound control." But not all data is retrieved, the call is cancelled. What happens and why is the memory not released?

Anyone an idea what is going on or/and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you dispose a resource doesn't mean that the framework is going to give back the memory. In fact, the server version of the framework will retain the allocated memory space for later reuse.

[How the garbage collection works in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

[A very useful blog for understanding the internals of garbage collection and performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/)

[From the same blog, see the block after the third note](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2003/12/02/two-things-to-avoid-for-better-memory-usage.aspx).